# vbsを使ってpowershellを呼び出した際にpowershellのスクリプトが落ちてしまう。

Tags: powershell, vbs

下記のようにvbsからpowershellを呼び出す仕掛けにしたいのですがpowershellが一瞬だけ開いてInputboxが表示されません。powershell単体で実行をすると問題なく起動してきます。

vbsのRunメソッドの引数で「0」⇒「1」に変更や「true」を「false」への変更は試しましたが事象は変わらず。原因がわからないためご教示ください。

##### test.vbs

```
Set objWShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
result = objWShell.Run ("%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File .\hoge\hoge.ps1",0,true)
WScript.Quit(result)
```

##### hoge.ps1

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$INPUT = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("入力して下さい。", "確認")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("受け付けました", "確認")
```

Comment: 手持ちの環境で再現したところ、呼び出し先のWindowを表示させるように設定した場合、メッセージボックスが表示されました。成功呼び出し例：
`result = objWShell.Run ("%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File .\hoge\hoge.ps1",1 ,true)`

一瞬開いて落ちるということは`.\hoge\hoge.ps1`のファイル取得に失敗している可能性が高いです。絶対パスで指定した場合はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なんとか無事解決させることができました。

Answer (score 1):

On Error Resume Next

Set objWShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
result = objWShell.Run ("%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\hoge.ps1",1,true)

WScript.Quit(result)